# put input type text in the center of an image

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I need to create an html page. In this html page, I need to have an image with an a `<input type="text "/>`. This input is in the middle of the image; this input type text also have the "search" icon inside the input on the right.

I tried to build the code in this way:

```
<html>
   <img src="./home/image.jpeg">
       <input type="text" name="food" placeholder="insert the food">  
       </input> <!-- this input has the icon search on the right-->
    </img>
<html>
```

Obviously it doesn't work. Is there a good way to make it work?

Comment: use css background-image?

Answer (score 0):

Put your input inside a div, and make the image the background-image of that div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with your question. can you upload a link. but you also Add a Background image to the input type text. Something like this:

input { background-image: url("search_icon.png"); position:absolute; }

Comment: am sorry.  a newbie to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

html:

```
<div class="bg">
   <input type="text" name="food" placeholder="insert the food">  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg{
   background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/");
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
   line-height:200px;
   text-align:center;
}
```